# what the meaning of c++11 codes using member function like below

Tags: c++11

i do not understand   "R (F::* /*mf*/)" ,R is a type ,after R it should be a reference parameters

```
template<typename F, typename R>
Fty make_adaptor(F fn, R (F::* /*mf*/)(const SemanticValues& sv) const) 
{
    return TypeAdaptor<R>(fn);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++11, this is perfectly valid C++98 code.

Answer (score 6):

It's a pointer to a member function. In particular:

```
R (F::* mf)(const SemanticValues& sv) const
```

is

- `* mf`: a pointer named `mf` (whose name is commented out)...
- `F::`: ...to a member function of `F`...
- `const SemanticValues& sv`: ...which accepts a const reference to `SemanticValues`...
- `R`: ...and returns a value of type `R`...
- `const`: ...and is itself const.

Comment: good to mention that this implementation of `make_adaptor`  method doesn't use second parameter, so its name was commented out (to avoid warnings)

Comment: TypeAdaptor is a struct name ，TypeAdaptor<R>(fn) is call the Constructor explicitly，why the make_adaptor return type is Fty that defined as typedef std::function<any (const SemanticValues& sv, any& dt)> Fty;

Comment: That's a different question, but briefly: `std::function` has an implicit templated conversion constructor that allows any functor with the correct signature to be converted to an `std::function` automatically. It's [(5) on this cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function). And the typedef `Fty` is just a shorthand, it doesn't change anything about the types involved.

Answer (score 0):

It is a type for some [pointer to member function](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c17401/C-Tutorial-PointertoMember-Function.htm).

BTW, in many cases, you could prefer using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) with [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).